# JSON Deserialize Byte Array

Tags: json, deserialize, blob

I'm porting over a rest client from .NET to Apex and in the class that gets initiated by deserializing the JSON response, there is a byte[].

C# Example:

```
 public class MyResponse
  {
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
  }
```

Wondering how to best handle this in apex?  Maybe change it to a Blob or just a String type would work?

I likely don't really care about the data in the byte[], I just don't want it to break the Deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the system that is creating the JSON is using base64 encoding for the image, yes use Blob.

Here is an example of the deserialization/serialization working with base64 in Apex:

```
@isTest
private class ImageTest {
    private class MyResponse {
        Blob Image;
    }
    @isTest
    static void test() {
        // 2x2 PNG image
        String s = '{"Image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACAgMAAAAP2OW3AAAADFBMVEWxf2/KgHhvwEfedoetG6yMAAAADElEQVQI12NoYCgAAAH0APFbzVilAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"}';
        MyResponse b = (MyResponse) JSON.deserialize(s, MyResponse.class);
        String ss = JSON.serialize(b);
        System.assertEquals(s, ss);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for proving it with a test. Hopefully thats how they are encoding it... Unfortunately, I haven't gotten to see an actual response yet.